# Как сделать выпадающее окно в ListView android?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

У меня есть ListView, в котором задан

```
        ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            ListView.setItemChecked(2, false);
```

Который заполняется через SimpleCursorAdapter rawQuerry запросом. Как мне сделать, что бы нажав на элемент списка вылезало окно , где я должен буду указать кол-во позиций этого элемента ( максимальное кол-во позиций указывается в другой колонке таблицы)  ,а потом еще одним запросом rawQurry просуммировать все время?
Сейчас мой код выглядит так

```
public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      try {


          ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
          ListView.setItemChecked(2, false);

          String Model = getIntent().getStringExtra("Model");
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Model, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          db = databaseHelper.open();
          c = db.rawQuery("select _id, OpType from kertime where Model='"+Model+"'"  , null);
          String[] headers = new String[]{COLUMN_OPTYPE};
          CAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                  c, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);

          ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

              public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                  Cursor tt = db.rawQuery("SELECT Time FROM KerTime where _id='"+id+"'", null);
                  tt.moveToFirst();
                  String click = tt.getString(tt.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_TIME));
                  int I = Integer.parseInt(click);
                  int Sum =+ I;
//                    TextView.setText(Sum);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sum - "+ Sum + " Click - " + click ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });

          ListView.setAdapter(CAdapter);
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
  }
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      // Закрываем подключение и курсор
      db.close();
  }
```

Где Column_Time - время, затрачиваемое на одну операцию OpType, а OpCount - максимальное колличество этих операций

Comment: повесить "слушатель" на список, добавить вывод диалогового окна или запуск активности (startActivityFirResult) для ввода данных.

Comment: А как посчитать сумму? Есть ли какой-то буфер , куда можно записать итоговую сумму, что бы по нажатию на следующий элемент списка он прибавился?

Comment: в адаптере сделайте переменную